# Error Installing Karma Using "npm install -g karma"

Tags: node.js, karma-runner

Trying to Install Karma using **npm install -g karma** in command prompt, in a Network wherein proxy is disabled. I am facing following issue -

**

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install -g karma
npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "karma"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.23
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! Error: EPERM, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log']
npm ERR!   errno: 50,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\npm-debug.log' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "karma"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.23
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno 50
npm ERR! stack Error: EPERM, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

**
From the error log i can understand that **running this command again as root/Administrator** is one of the option but i do not have Admin rights so can't try it.

If you have any idea/ other option, please let know how to resolve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Please try running this command again as root/Administrator" have you done that?

Comment: Thanks for the information :).
I don't have admin rights, so can't try this option.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem (for me and many others) is an outdated version of npm itself.
There have been issues with this, or any yeoman generator for that matter, and node v0.12. There has been no permanent solution other than to revert node back to v0.10 or v0.10.36...