# Installing karma with npm on Windows 8

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm, karma-runner

I'm attempting to install karma.  The machine is windows 8.1.  I have node v0.12.2 installed on the system.

I run the command `npm install -g karma`

And I get the following output....

```
> C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\
> node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws>if not defined
> npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\n
> ode-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (rebuild) Building the
> projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
> please add the "/m" switch.
> C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io
> \node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj(18,3):
> error M SB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props"
> was not found. Co nfirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is
> correct, and that the file e xists on disk.
> C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io
> \node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj(18,3):
> error M SB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props"
> was not found. Co nfirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is
> correct, and that the file e xists on disk.
> 
> > ws@0.4.31 install C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\nod
> e_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
> node_modules\ws
> > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
> 
> 
> C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\
> node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws>if
> n ot defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\b
> in\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
> )  else (r ebuild) Building the projects in this solution one at a
> time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
> C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io
> \node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-lient\node_modules\ws\bu
> ild\bufferutil.vcxproj(18,3): error MSB4019: The imported project
> "C:\Microsoft .Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path
> in the <Import> declar ation is correct, and that the file exists on
> disk.
> C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io
> \node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\bu
> ild\validation.vcxproj(18,3): error MSB4019: The imported project
> "C:\Microsoft .Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path
> in the <Import> declar ation is correct, and that the file exists on
> disk. karma@0.12.32
> C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma 
> ├── di@0.0.1 
> ├── graceful-fs@2.0.3 
> ├── colors@0.6.2 
> ├── rimraf@2.2.8 
> ├── mime@1.2.11
> ├── q@0.9.7 
> ├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.1, lru-cache@2.6.4) 
> ├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10) 
> ├── source-map@0.1.43 (amdefine@0.1.0) 
> ├── glob@3.2.11 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.3.0) 
> ├── lodash@2.4.2 
> ├── expand-braces@0.1.1 (array-uniq@1.0.2, array-slice@0.2.3, braces@0.1.5) 
> ├── log4js@0.6.25 (async@0.2.10, underscore@1.8.2, readable-stream@1.0.33, semve r@4.3.4) 
> ├── http-proxy@0.10.4 (pkginfo@0.3.0, utile@0.2.1) 
> ├── chokidar@1.0.1 (arrify@1.0.0, is-glob@1.1.3, glob-parent@1.2.0, async-each@0 .1.6, is-binary-path@1.0.0, readdirp@1.3.0, anymatch@1.3.0) 
> ├── useragent@2.0.10 (lru-cache@2.2.4) 
> ├── connect@2.26.6 (fresh@0.2.4, cookie@0.1.2, pause@0.0.1, cookie-signature@1.0 .5, response-time@2.0.1, vhost@3.0.0, bytes@1.0.0, on-headers@1.0.0, basic-auth- connect@1.0.0, media-typer@0.3.0, parseurl@1.3.0, depd@0.4.5, connect-timeout@1.
 3.0, cookie-parser@1.3.5, debug@2.0.0, qs@2.2.4, finalhandler@0.2.0, method-over ride@2.2.0, serve-favicon@2.1.7, morgan@1.3.2, multiparty@3.3.2, type-is@1.5.7, serve-static@1.6.5, compression@1.1.2, errorhandler@1.2.4, csurf@1.6.6, express-session@1.8.2, body-parser@1.8.4, serve-index@1.2.1) 
> ├── memoizee@0.3.8 (next-tick@0.2.2, lru-queue@0.1.0, timers-ext@0.1.0,
d@0.1.1,  event-emitter@0.3.3, es6-weak-map@0.1.4, es5-ext@0.10.7) 
> └── socket.io@1.3.5 (debug@2.1.0, has-binary-data@0.1.3,
socket.io-adapter@0.3.1 , socket.io-parser@2.2.4, engine.io@1.5.1,
socket.io-client@1.3.5)
```

I'm unsure how to fix this error.

I've googled for the MSB4019 error and came up with this page ([npm install -g karma error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774929/npm-install-g-karma-error-msb4019-the-imported-project-c-microsoft-cpp-defau)) where they suggest running `npm install --msvs_version=2013` and I got phantomjs installation errors relating to ELIFECYCLE.   I further tried `npm install --msvs_version=2012`, as suggested in a comment and did not get errors -- but was still unable to install karma (same errors as above).  Without Visual Studio installed, I'm unable to do the entire solution (though I don't think karma requires a full Visual Studio install)

This person ([Error Installing Karma Using "npm install -g karma"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26122094/error-installing-karma-using-npm-install-g-karma)) also is struggling to install karma.  I do have admin rights, so I tried running it as an administrator.  That also failed, but with a different output:

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g karma
npm WARN engine karma@0.12.32: wanted: {"node":"~0.8 || ~0.10"} (current: {"node
":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.6
\


> ws@0.5.0 install C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\n
ode_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.
io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (no
de "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_module
s\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (rebuild)
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\build\bind
ing.sln]
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\build\bind
ing.sln]

> ws@0.4.31 install C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\
node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-clie
nt\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.
io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws>i
f not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\np
m\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else
 (rebuild)
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine
.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\binding.sln]
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine
.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\binding.sln]
karma@0.12.32 C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma
├── di@0.0.1
├── graceful-fs@2.0.3
├── colors@0.6.2
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── mime@1.2.11
├── q@0.9.7
├── lodash@2.4.2
├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.1, lru-cache@2.6.4)
├── glob@3.2.11 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.3.0)
├── useragent@2.0.10 (lru-cache@2.2.4)
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10)
├── source-map@0.1.43 (amdefine@0.1.0)
├── expand-braces@0.1.1 (array-uniq@1.0.2, array-slice@0.2.3, braces@0.1.5)
├── log4js@0.6.25 (async@0.2.10, underscore@1.8.2, readable-stream@1.0.33, semve
r@4.3.4)
├── http-proxy@0.10.4 (pkginfo@0.3.0, utile@0.2.1)
├── memoizee@0.3.8 (lru-queue@0.1.0, next-tick@0.2.2, timers-ext@0.1.0, d@0.1.1,
 event-emitter@0.3.3, es6-weak-map@0.1.4, es5-ext@0.10.7)
├── connect@2.26.6 (fresh@0.2.4, cookie@0.1.2, pause@0.0.1, cookie-signature@1.0
.5, vhost@3.0.0, response-time@2.0.1, on-headers@1.0.0, basic-auth-connect@1.0.0
, bytes@1.0.0, media-typer@0.3.0, parseurl@1.3.0, depd@0.4.5, qs@2.2.4, finalhan
dler@0.2.0, cookie-parser@1.3.5, method-override@2.2.0, multiparty@3.3.2, morgan
@1.3.2, body-parser@1.8.4, connect-timeout@1.3.0, debug@2.0.0, type-is@1.5.7, se
rve-static@1.6.5, compression@1.1.2, serve-index@1.2.1, errorhandler@1.2.4, csur
f@1.6.6, serve-favicon@2.1.7, express-session@1.8.2)
├── chokidar@1.0.1 (arrify@1.0.0, is-glob@1.1.3, glob-parent@1.2.0, async-each@0
.1.6, is-binary-path@1.0.0, readdirp@1.3.0, anymatch@1.3.0)
└── socket.io@1.3.5 (debug@2.1.0, has-binary-data@0.1.3, socket.io-parser@2.2.4,
 socket.io-adapter@0.3.1, engine.io@1.5.1, socket.io-client@1.3.5)
```

I should note that `npm install -g grunt` and `npm install -g bower` both seem to complete fine.   (though I should note that when attempting to run `grunt` on my project -- which works on a different system -- just hangs.

ANyway - searching on the errors presented when run as administartor,

> MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component
>   "VCBuild.exe".  To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2)
>   install Microsoft Visua l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the
>   component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.

I found this github page for the karma runner: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/536 where it was suggested that one go here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx and get the Windows 8 SDK.   I've downloaded the Windows 8 SDK and have gotten the message that "The features installed on this computer all up-to-date".

Further, I've found a few other people that have mentioned ensuring that the path to your VCBuild.exe file is in your path.  Which I have done.

After adding that, I get a whole new set of errors when running `npm install -g karma`.  Unfortunately, I can't paste it all here as it just flows off the command line buffer.  Here is a sampling:

```
C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket
.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws
\node_modules\nan\nan.h(873): error C2228: left of '.length' must have class/st
ruct/union [C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_mo
dules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\nod
e_modules\ws\build\binding.sln]
..\src\validation.cc(108): error C2248: 'v8::HandleScope::HandleScope' : cannot
 access protected member declared in class 'v8::HandleScope' [C:\Users\jfederer
-ou\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\
socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\binding.sl
n]
..\src\validation.cc(109): error C2664: 'v8::FunctionTemplate::New' : cannot co
nvert parameter 1 from 'void (__cdecl *)(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<T> &)'
to 'v8::Isolate *' [C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma
\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-cl
ient\node_modules\ws\build\binding.sln]
..\src\validation.cc(112): error C2039: 'NewSymbol' : is not a member of 'v8::S
tring' [C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_module
s\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_mo
dules\ws\build\binding.sln]
..\src\validation.cc(112): error C3861: 'NewSymbol': identifier not found [C:\U
sers\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\
node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\bui
ld\binding.sln]
..\src\validation.cc(134): error C2660: 'v8::True' : function does not take 0 a
rguments [C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modu
les\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_
modules\ws\build\binding.sln]
..\src\validation.cc(134): error C2660: 'v8::False' : function does not take 0
arguments [C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_mod
ules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node
_modules\ws\build\binding.sln]
```

I removed my additions to the vcbuild.exe in the system path and the errors returned to the previous "MSB3428" errors.

I have downloaded and installed (Convoluted method found via google to get it to install on Windows 8) the suggested .NET Framework 2.0 SDK.   No change.

I have downloaded Visual Studio Community edition and got some new errors:
(again, more than fit int he cmd-line buffer, so this is just a snippet)

```
          C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules
  \socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
  odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(84) : see declaration of 'NanSetPointerSafe'
C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io
\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\no
de_modules\nan\nan.h(858): warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t'
 to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
dules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\e
ngine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io
\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\no
de_modules\nan\nan.h(873): error C2065: 'value' : undeclared identifier [C:\Use
rs\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_
modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\va
lidation.vcxproj]
C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io
\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\no
de_modules\nan\nan.h(873): error C2228: left of '.length' must have class/struc
t/union [C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\
socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modu
les\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
          type is 'unknown-type'
C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io
\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\no
de_modules\nan\nan.h(873): error C2780: 'bool NanSetPointerSafe(T *,T)' : expec
ts 2 arguments - 1 provided [C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine
.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules
  \socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
  odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(84) : see declaration of 'NanSetPointerSafe'
..\src\validation.cc(108): error C2248: 'v8::HandleScope::HandleScope' : cannot
 access protected member declared in class 'v8::HandleScope' [C:\Users\xxxxxxx
\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\soc
ket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vc
xproj]
          C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.node-gyp\0.12.2\deps\v8\include\v8.h(816) : see de
  claration of 'v8::HandleScope::HandleScope'
          C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.node-gyp\0.12.2\deps\v8\include\v8.h(800) : see de
  claration of 'v8::HandleScope'
..\src\validation.cc(109): error C2664: 'v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> v8::Fu
nctionTemplate::New(v8::Isolate *,v8::FunctionCallback,v8::Handle<v8::Value>,v8
::Handle<v8::Signature>,int)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'void (__cdecl *
)(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &)' to 'v8::Isolate *' [C:\Users\jf
ederer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modul
es\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validat
ion.vcxproj]
          There is no context in which this conversion is possible
..\src\validation.cc(112): error C2039: 'NewSymbol' : is not a member of 'v8::S
tring' [C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\s
ocket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modul
es\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.node-gyp\0.12.2\deps\v8\include\v8.h(1599) : see d
  eclaration of 'v8::String'
..\src\validation.cc(112): error C3861: 'NewSymbol': identifier not found [C:\U
sers\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\nod
e_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\
validation.vcxproj]
..\src\validation.cc(134): error C2660: 'v8::True' : function does not take 0 a
rguments [C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules
\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_mod
ules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
..\src\validation.cc(134): error C2660: 'v8::False' : function does not take 0
arguments [C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_module
s\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_mo
dules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
karma@0.12.32 C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma
├── di@0.0.1
├── graceful-fs@2.0.3
├── colors@0.6.2
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── mime@1.2.11
├── q@0.9.7
├── lodash@2.4.2
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10)
├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.1, lru-cache@2.6.4)
├── useragent@2.0.10 (lru-cache@2.2.4)
├── source-map@0.1.43 (amdefine@0.1.0)
├── glob@3.2.11 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.3.0)
├── memoizee@0.3.8 (next-tick@0.2.2, lru-queue@0.1.0, timers-ext@0.1.0, d@0.1.1,
 event-emitter@0.3.3, es6-weak-map@0.1.4, es5-ext@0.10.7)
├── expand-braces@0.1.1 (array-uniq@1.0.2, array-slice@0.2.3, braces@0.1.5)
├── log4js@0.6.25 (async@0.2.10, underscore@1.8.2, readable-stream@1.0.33, semve
r@4.3.4)
├── http-proxy@0.10.4 (pkginfo@0.3.0, utile@0.2.1)
├── chokidar@1.0.1 (arrify@1.0.0, is-glob@1.1.3, glob-parent@1.2.0, async-each@0
.1.6, is-binary-path@1.0.1, readdirp@1.3.0, anymatch@1.3.0)
├── connect@2.26.6 (cookie@0.1.2, fresh@0.2.4, pause@0.0.1, cookie-signature@1.0
.5, response-time@2.0.1, vhost@3.0.0, on-headers@1.0.0, bytes@1.0.0, basic-auth-
connect@1.0.0, media-typer@0.3.0, parseurl@1.3.0, depd@0.4.5, cookie-parser@1.3.
5, qs@2.2.4, connect-timeout@1.3.0, debug@2.0.0, finalhandler@0.2.0, method-over
ride@2.2.0, serve-favicon@2.1.7, multiparty@3.3.2, type-is@1.5.7, compression@1.
1.2, serve-index@1.2.1, errorhandler@1.2.4, morgan@1.3.2, csurf@1.6.6, serve-sta
tic@1.6.5, express-session@1.8.2, body-parser@1.8.4)
└── socket.io@1.3.5 (has-binary-data@0.1.3, debug@2.1.0, socket.io-parser@2.2.4,
 socket.io-adapter@0.3.1, engine.io@1.5.1, socket.io-client@1.3.5)
```

Has ANYONE gotten Karma to install with npm on windows 8?
Help?

**UPDATE**

Uninstalled node.  Deleted all npm, npm-cache, and node directories.  Deleted all temp package directories (.bower, .node-gyp, etc). Rebooted.  Cleared path of any node related items as well. Rebooted again.

Installed Node.js **64 bit**.  Rebooted.
Installed newest version of npm.  Rebooted.
Installed `npm install --global yo bower grunt-cli`.  Rebooted.
Cloned github repo (which is basically just a yeoman-scaffolded angular app) into a new folder.
Expanded the commandline buffer and ran `npm install`.  Note, the package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "learncontacts",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "repository": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.12.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-filerev": "^2.1.2",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "^0.4.3",
    "grunt-karma": "*",
    "grunt-newer": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-svgmin": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "^3.0.0",
    "grunt-wiredep": "^2.0.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "*",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "*",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.1.0",
    "time-grunt": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  }
}
```

... that resulted in a boatload of errors (thousands of lines).  Most of them seem to be based around socket.io.  I can't put more text in this post, so I can't show it all.

That said, I soildered on as if nothing was wrong and ran my `bower install`.  That completed without error.  When done I was able to succesfully `grunt serve` and `grunt test`.

From the little research I've done, it seems that if socket.io fails, there is a fallback.  I suspect that's why it is working now.

... that said, anyone have any thoughts so we can sort some of this out?

Further research shows a potential solution in installing socket.io: [NPM - Can't install socket.IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469086/npm-cant-install-socket-io)    (for what it's worth, I tried it an it did not work...)

Comment: not directly related to your karma issue, but to install grunt it is ```npm install -g grunt-cli``` which will give you access to ```grunt``` binary. Then into each project, you must install grunt as local dependency with ```npm install grunt```

Comment: I d suggest you try to install ```ws``` separately, it seems to be related to that package specifically.

Comment: `npm install -g ws` works without any issues.